# How to restrict function from printing condition true value

Tags: function, html, html-email, idoc

I'm working on IDOC script wherein a function rsRename(code below) returns TRUE/FALSE if the function is a success/fail respectively. Now I'm using this function in an HTML email template and it prints value 1 for the condition TRUE in the email. I want to restrict this function from printing value 1 in Email. Definition of rsRename function: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21043_01/doc.1111/e10726/c08_config_ref263.htm

```
"<tr>       
         <td align ="center" vertical-align="top" width="60%" style='background:#E6E6D8;min-width:600px'>    
            <p style="padding-left:10px">        
            <$executeService("GET_SENDTOWORKFLOW_HISTORY_EMAIL_DETAILS")$>
                 <$numrowSTOWFH = rsNumRows("SendtoWorkflowActionHistory")$>
            <$executeService("GET_WORKFLOW_HISTORY_EMAIL_DETAILS")$>
                 <$numrowWFH = rsNumRows("WorkflowActionHistory")$>      
            <$if numrowWFH gt 0$>                    
                    <$rsRename("WorkflowActionHistory", rsNewName)$>
            <$else$>                     
                    <$rsRename("SendtoWorkflowActionHistory", rsNewName)$>
            <$endif$>   
                <span style="font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;font-size:12pt">
                    <b>Reason:&nbsp;</b></span>
                <span style="font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;font-size:12pt;color:blue">
                    <b><$if xPurposeForSubmission$><$getFieldViewValue("xPurposeForSubmission",xPurposeForSubmission,"Reason")$><$endif$></span></b>
         </td>  
</tr>
"
```

Comment: Am i reaching the right group??? guide me if tagging other techs. will help me resolve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the 'exec' command:

exec  Executes an expression and suppresses the output
(does not display the expression on the page).
In earlier versions of Idoc Script, the exec keyword
was required to suppress the value of any variable
from appearing in the output file. In the current
version, the exec keyword is needed only to suppress
an expression from appearing in the output file.

Answer (score 0):

putting the code within div tag as   CODE  resolved the issue on my system and the mail template do not prints "1" for true condition anymore.

However the issue still remains and value "1" gets printed when the email is opened on a mail box configured on my mobile. Any further help how can i restrict this on a mobile device as well?